Bind9 Response Rate limiting for a specific subnet
I want to configure bind9 so that a specific IP range is restricted from sending too many requests.
Suppose I want to limit the range 2001:dead:beef/48 to 5 requests per second. This can, according to the documentation, be done by combining a 'view' with a 'rate-limit' clause in some mysterious way,  no example syntax is given. I can find an example for the whole internet at 'https://serverfault.com/questions/490245/bind-dns-rate-limit-and-values-for-responses-per-second-and-window'.
Next, suppose I want to block this range entirely. How would I do that / what's the best way of achieving this? Does a rate limit of zero mean no requests or unlimited, or do you do this some other way?

IPv6 is so weird...
